# FirebaseFirestore error <FirebaseOptions.getProjectId() cannot be null>

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying out the, now available, `FirebaseFirestore` for `Xamarin`, but when i try to get an instance:

```
App = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(context);
Store = FirebaseFirestore.GetInstance(App);
```

Like when using `FirebaseAuth`:

```
Auth = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(App);
```

It throws `FirebaseOptions.getProjectId() cannot be null`

Is it still borken, or am i doing it wrong?

Comment: I do have it, and am already initializing the `FirebaseApp` with it, and even tried to do it manually but still.

Comment: @SushiHangover Actually i just found out that the problem is with the `FirebaseApp` itself not giving a `ProjectId`. I do have a `google-service.json` file set to build as `GoogleServiceJson`.

Comment: What's version of FirebaseFirestore NuGet package are you using? And have you tried to get the instance by using `FirebaseFirestore.Instance` ?

Comment: @Explisam did you resolve this issue? You mentioned you found the problem with the json file. But how did you resolve?

Comment: Nope i couldn't get it to work, FirebaseApp didn't generate a ProjectId because i'm guessing it couldn't detect the google service file, although i strictly followed the documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was [reported to the Xamarin Google Play services library](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/104).

Finally got a response from support, there is nothing we have done wrong, its an bug on Xamarin's side.

We are currently waiting for this [fix](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/commit/723ebdc00867a4c70c51ad2d0dcbd36474ce8ff1) to be released.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and solved it by changing

`'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`

to

`'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'`

in my project `build.gradle` file. I'm not sure if this applies to Xamarin.

Comment: @rsteilbery thanks for your reply, but yes it doesn't help us resolve this issue for xamarin.